# get all data-task-id from table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this table

```
  <table id="tblTasks">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Due</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have a table as above and script as below

```
<script id="taskRow" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td>${task}</td>
        <td>
            <time datetime="${requiredBy}">${requiredBy}</time>
        </td>
        </td>
        <td>${category}</td>
        <td>
            <nav>
                <a href="#" class="editRow" data-task-id="${id}">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="completed">Complete</a>
                <a href="#" class="deleteRow" data-task-id="${id}">Delete</a>
            </nav>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Basically, how it works at the moment is when I click the Delete button the code below will run

```
storageEngine.delete('task', $(evt.target).data().taskId, ....
```

taskId is the value from `data-task-id="${id}"` now, I have another button that delete all the tasks. I'm trying to cycle through all the rows in the table and find the Delete button then apply the storageEngine.delete but don't know how.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dataList = $(".deleteRow").map(function() {
 return $(this).data("task-id");
}).get();
console.log(dataList.join('|'));
```

Comment: can I add a condition to it so it adds to the list if the first td of that row has a certain class?

Comment: Why don't you add another data attribute in the same element which contains  data-task-id. Then you can add the condition in the function.

Comment: nvm, i just got it. Thanks a lot!